# How can I implement Stream to get list of sub collection for each docs ? -flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

I'm try to get `sub collection` from each doc `ex.clothes,notifer` witch I have more docs , that means I don't know its id ,My bossiness Logic was to fetch the main `collection` for getting all the `documents` and then for each doc get its `sub collection` and I did that with Future implementation ,but I can't do it using Stream to return the final `Sub Collection SnapShots` `ex.properitres` for listing to changes . by `Future` it rebuild every time and if I stop widget rebuilding by `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` I could not get any `Firesotre` changes . Thanks in advance .[image]

[image]

here is my Future implementation but again I need this implementation by Stream ^_^:

```
Future<List<Category>> getPropertiesDocs() async {
    List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> _firstListOfDocs = [];
    List<Category> _categorListOfDocs = [];
    List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> _secoudListOfDocs = [];

    final QuerySnapshot result = await _firebaseFirestore.collection('categories').get();
    result.docs.forEach((element) {
      // print(element.id);
      _firstListOfDocs.add(element);
    });
    for (var i in _firstListOfDocs) {
      final QuerySnapshot snapshot2 = await i.reference.collection("properties").get();
      snapshot2.docs.forEach((element) {
        _secoudListOfDocs.add(element);
        _categorListOfDocs.add(Category.fromSnapShpt(element));
      });
    }
    _firstListOfDocs.clear();
    _secoudListOfDocs.clear();
    return _categorListOfDocs;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your future implementation,

1. You want to get all documents in `categories` collection.
2. For each document in `categories` collection, you want to get the `properties` subcollection.

For the first requirement, we can simply stream the categories collection.
For the second requirement, it is not advisable to stream `properties` collection from each `categories` subcollection. This won't scale well with large datasets.

Instead we will stream the collectionGroup `properties`. Streaming the collection group `properties` will fetch all collections with the name `properties` (no matter the location). To effectively use this, no other collection should be named `properties` (except the ones you want to fetch), or you rename your collection to something distinct like `properties_categories`.

```
// this streamBuilder will fetch stream for categories collection.
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _firebaseFirestore.collection('categories').snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Delivery>> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) return Message();
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
      return Loading();
      print('categories snapshot result');
      print(snapshot.data.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList());
      // _firstListOfDocs is given below (renamed to _categoryDocs)
      List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> _categoryDocs = snapshot.data.docs;

    // this streamBuilder will fetch all documents in all collections called properties.
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _firebaseFirestore.collectionGroup('properties').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> propertiesSnapshot) {
        if (propertiesSnapshot.hasError) return Message();
        if (propertiesSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
          return Loading();

        print('properties snapshot result');
        print(propertiesSnapshot.data.docs.map((e) => e.data()).toList());
        // _secoudListOfDocs is given below (and renamed to _propertiesDocs)
        List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> _propertiesDocs = propertiesSnapshot.data.docs;
        // _categorListOfDocs is given below (and renamed to _categories)
        List<Category> _categories = propertiesSnapshot.data.docs
          .map((e) => Category.fromSnapShpt(e)).toList();
        // return your widgets here.
        return Text('Done');
      },
    );
  },
)
```

If your reason for fetching `categories` collection data is simply to loop over it and fetch `properties` collection, then you can delete the first streamBuilder above since we do not need to use it to fetch `properties` collection.